# Dynamically changing select value of jQuery Mobile select box

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have dynamically created select menu. How can I dynamically change selected value to third value(Apple).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select id="stylex" data-mini="true">   </select>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var wid_settings = ["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango"];

wid_settings_refresh();

function wid_settings_refresh() {
    var index;    
    for (index = 0; index < wid_settings.length; index++) {
        $('#stylex').append('<option value='+index+'>'+wid_settings[index]+'</option>');
    }
    $('#stylex').listview('refresh'); 
}

// this is not working
$('#stylex').val(3);
$('#stylex').selectmenu("refresh");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhLt2sxj/4/)

Comment: Code from JSFiddle added to the question. JSFiddle link formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhLt2sxj/5/

```
var wid_settings = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

wid_settings_refresh();

function wid_settings_refresh() {
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < wid_settings.length; index++) {

        $('#stylex').append('<option value=' + index + '>' + wid_settings[index] + '</option>');
    }
    $('#stylex').val(3);
    //$('#stylex').listview('refresh'); //not necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works inside "wid_settings_refresh" function but how about if I want to change value in separate function? jsfiddle.net/rhLt2sxj/6/

Comment: basically your $('#stylex').listview('refresh');  is wrong. and execution is stopping there